# How can I upload files to put in my question?

Tags: support, asking

How can I put files in my question? I want to put a link to a Minecraft world (`.zip`) on a question I asked so others can download it and look, but I can't seem to figure out how to do that. Is there a way I can?

Comment: why would they need the world?

Answer (score 5):

Put your file on MediaFire, Dropbox, or some other public file sharing site, copy its link and put it into your post, preferably using [link syntax](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LWErcuHm_C4) (`[click here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com)`) instead of a direct URL https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/15632/250180 because that looks so ugly and painful to my eyes.

Hopefully you know this already, but Arqade is not the place to share your worlds and advertise them! Such questions will be closed and answers deleted.

And also consider whether the world download is actually needed for others to clue into what your problem is.

Comment: It wasnt for advertising

Comment: @CiurkitboyN another thing to consider is very few people would actually download the world, so just keep that in mind

Comment: That link was super useful, I didn't even know that before in the months I've been on this site! I think I've been doing that wrong and I bet many others are too

Comment: Also, try to stick with something like MediaFire and steer clear from things like Google Drive because that's not very anonymizing